# Вывод ссылок через foreach из ассоциативного массива в PHP

Tags: php, html, ссылки, foreach

Изучая цикл foreach и ассоциативные массивы в PHP столкнулся со следующим кодом для примитивной навигации.

```
$menu = array("Home" => "index.php", "Contact" => "contact.php", "About" => "about.php");

foreach($menu as $link=>$href)
{
echo "<li><a href=\"$href\">", $link, "</a></li>";
}
```

И вот здесь есть такая запись `href=\"$href\"`, которая присваивает адресу значение из массива. Что конкретно значат символы `\"`? Чем их можно заменить или это такой строгий синтаксис?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\ - экранирует спецсимвол двойная кавычка.
можно заменить " на '

```
$menu = array("Home" => "index.php", "Contact" => "contact.php", "About" =>   "about.php");

foreach($menu as $link=>$href)
{
    echo "<li><a href='$href'>", $link, "</a></li>";
}
```